# Поиск инструкции из GDB в файле

Tags: hex, gdb

Дизассемблирую участок кода в GDB с аргументом /r, вот одна из выводимых строк:

```
0xf343d08e <+350>:  80 3d 30 c8 63 f3 00    cmpb   $0x0,0xf363c830
```

`80 3d 30 c8 63 f3 00` это инструкция в raw виде как я понял, пробую искать ее открыв файл с дизассемблируемом кодом в HEX редакторе, но не нахожу, почему так и как мне найти эту инструкцию в HEX редакторе?

Answer (score 1):

Давно не пользовался gdb и никогда не пользовался /r, но судя по всему, тут динамический адрес в ОЗУ, это не настоящий бинарный код.

А чтобы получить то, что там у вас реально лежит, нужно использовать команды вроде:

`x/b 0xdeadbeef`

где 0xdeadbeef - адрес конкретного байта
или

```
print
```

Подробнее см. документацию по GDB.

Еще gdb умеет дизассемблировать бинарник до запуска, и тогда везде все будет фактическое. Нужно только найти то же самое место.

Comment: x/b выводит тоже что и disasseble /r

Comment: @ВіталійКарпенко А вообще этот участок есть в этом файле? Может, он как-то иначе грузится - DLL там...

Comment: да, точно есть, ошибки в этом плане быть не может(есть исходники), грузится он как раз из разделяемой библиотеки, в ней я и ищу